# Make AJAX request using mootools and node.js with expressjs

Tags: ajax, node.js, mootools

I'm trying establish an AJAX connection on node 0.10.3 using mootools. My code is:

**Client**

```
var ajax = new Request({
url: '/register',
method: 'post',
onSuccess: function(responseText){
    console.log(responseText);
}
 })

 var json = {data:'data'};
 ajax.send(JSON.stringify(json));
 //ajax.send(json);
```

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(1344);

app.post('/register', function(req,res){
     //Auth.register()
     console.log(req.body);
     res.contentType('json');
     res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) })
})
```

The connection is working Ok. On the client I get the response. So the `console.log(responseText)` inside the OnSucces method is printing the correct value.

But on the server side, the `console.log(req.body)` is `undefined`.

I have a few doubts here. Does mootools converts the javascript object to a json string? Is it necessary to convert de object at all? What is the correct way of sending information trough AJAX to node? Is this `ajax.send(JSON.stringify(json));` OK? Or is it like this `ajax.send(json)`;?

Do I need to specify the headers to be json?

Apart for solving the particular problem, it would be nice some article, o some feedback to definitely clarify this concepts around node.js.

**EDIT**

I'm going to post the correct code, for those who are facing a similar problem. Noah was right about the parser, but there is another detail, the parser is expecting for the key data. Luckily I was using data as example!

**Client**

```
var ajax = new Request({
   url: '/register',
   method: 'post',
   onSuccess: function(responseText){
       console.log(responseText); //Logs "some": "{\"response\":\"json\"}"
   }
})
ajax.send({data:{ok:'OK'}});
```

**Server**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.listen(1344);

app.post('/register', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body); //logs {ok:'OK'}
    res.contentType('json');
    res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted you are missing the bodyParser middleware `app.use(express.bodyParser()`.

After you add the bodyParser middleware you will be able to access `req.body`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(app.router)
```

Comment: Just a comment on mootools - you don't need to stringify the json object when you send the data - mootools request excepts objects: [http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Request:send](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Request:send)

Comment: Thanks, that was something I had doubts about.Now works like a charm.